# Dijkstra's algorithm not working

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

I'm creating a game for a school project, and I want to use Dijkstra's algorithm as part of an AI for the objects the player needs to dodge.

So I have a graph (an adjacency matrix) and I want to use Dijkstra to get the path from each object to the player, but right now when I call the algorithm, it will not find the player if the player comes after the object.

In my understanding, Dijkstra's algorithm should visit all of the nodes until it finds the destination, but it doesn't in my case.

Here's what my algorithm looks like so far:

```
Node* Graph::DijkstrasAlgorithm(Node* sNode, Node* dNode){
    std::cout<<"Hello Dijkstra!!"<<std::endl;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->nodeList.size(); ++i){
        nodeList.at(i)->setDistance(INT_MAX);
        nodeList.at(i)->setVisited(false);
    }
    std::cout<<"everything is set"<<std::endl;
    sNode->setDistance(0);
    int numberVisited = 0;
    Node* u = new Node();
    std::cout<<"before while lus"<<std::endl;
    while(numberVisited < numberOfNodes){
        u->setDistance(INT_MAX);
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < this->nodeList.size(); ++j){
            if((u->getDistance() > this->nodeList.at(j)->getDistance()) && !this->nodeList.at(j)->isVisited() ){
                u = this->nodeList.at(j);
                u->setVisited(true);
                numberVisited++;
            }
        }

    std::cout<<u->getNodeName()<<"=="<<dNode->getNodeName()<<std::endl;
        if((u == dNode) || (u->getDistance() == INT_MAX)){
            std::cout<<"true"<<std::endl;
            break;
        }


        for(int k = 0; k < u->numberOfneighbors(); ++k){
            if(!u->getNeighbors(k)->isVisited())
            {
            //  std::cout<<u->getDistance()<<std::endl;
                int alt = u->getDistance() + 1;
                if( alt < u->getNeighbors(k)->getDistance()){
                     u->getNeighbors(k)->setDistance(alt);
                     u->getNeighbors(k)->setPrevious(u);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    std::vector<Node* > stack;
    u = dNode;
    while(u->getPrevious() != NULL){
        stack.insert(stack.begin(), u);
        u = u->getPrevious();
    }
    if(!stack.empty())
        return stack.at(0);
    else
        return sNode;


}
```

In this case, `dNode` is the destination node, and `sNode` is the start node.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have stepped through it with a debugger on a simple test case?

Comment: Better suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) then here. Also try to correct the mistakes in your question(I mean the **question** not the code) at least partially.

Comment: i had created a square graph with size of 4 by 4, i checked if the graph was correct on different sizes and the graph is generated perfect, but on the 4 by 4 it still doesn't work as i would espect, i have used the pseudo code at [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm[/link] as a guide line

Comment: @Bjorn I've tried my best to clean up this question; can you clarify what you mean by "player comes after the object"?

Comment: @izomorphius: codereview only accepts questions about working code. If it was asked there they would send it back here to get fixed before they review it.

Comment: @atomicinf if i have a square graph with a size of 10 * 10, then if we start counting at 0. then when mine start node is at node 15 and mine destenation node is at node 4 then mine dijkstra could not find the destenation, but is i the otherway round than it is not a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dijkstra algorithm you mark as visited only the node to which the shortest augmenting path points to. I can see an error you make here:

```
u = this->nodeList.at(j);
u->setVisited(true);
```

Don't mark the nodes as visited immediately.

Mark as visited only the node `u` will point to after the cycle

```
for(unsigned int j = 0; j < this->nodeList.size(); ++j){
```

Otherwise for every improvement you will mark the node as visited, not even processing all of them.

Comment: thanks, with your answer i've got it working. i need to put the visited and the increment of numberVisited outside the for.

Answer (score 1):

It does not even look like Dijkstra algorithm.

To implement Dijkstra algorithms you need to maintain two lists of nodes:

- A list of searched nodes
- A SORTED list of edge nodes.
  Each node in this list has the cost to reach this location.

I see neither of these lists in your code.

You are also storing the cost in the node. This will not work as the cost to reach a node will depend on the route (unless you can store multiple costs associated with node).

I would expect the code to look like this:

```
 // pseudo code.
 // Note all features used are strictly available
 //
 Node* Graph::DijkstrasAlgorithm(Node* sNode, Node* dNode)
 {
     std::list<Node*>                    searchedNodes;
     std::list<std::pair<Node*, cost>>   edgeNodes;

     edgeNodes.push_sorted(sNode, 0);

     while(!edgeNodes.empty())
     {
          std::pair<Node*, cost>  next = edgeNodes.pop_front();
          searchedNodes.push_back(next.first);

          if (next.first == dnode)
          {   // We found the route
              return STUFF;
          }

          for(Edge* edge, next.first->getEdges())
          {
              if (searchedNodes.find(edge->dst) != searchedNodes.end())
              {   continue;
              }

              edgeNodes.push_sorted(dest.dst, next.second + edge->cost);
          }
     }
 }
```